# How do you edit the command line in an external editor?

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface, editor, psreadline

#### tl;dr

I want to find a Powershell version of the `bash` `edit-and-execute-command` widget or the `zsh` `edit-command-line` widget.

#### Background

Short commands get executed directly on the command-line, long complicated commands get executed from scripts. However, before they become "long", it helps to be able to test medium length commands on the command-line. To assist in this effort, editing the command in an external editor becomes very helpful. AFAIK Powershell does not support this natively as e.g. `bash` and `zsh` do.

#### My current attempt

I am new to Powershell, so I'm bound to make many mistakes, but I *have* come up with a working solution using the features of the `[Microsoft.Powershell.PSConsoleReadLine]` class.  I am able to copy the current command-line to a file, edit the file, and then re-inject the edited version back into the command-line:

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord "Alt+e" -ScriptBlock {
  $CurrentInput = $null

  # Copy current command-line input, save it to a file and clear it
  [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::GetBufferState([ref] $CurrentInput, [ref] $null)
  Set-Content -Path "C:\Temp\ps_${PID}.txt" -Value "$CurrentInput"
  [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::KillRegion()

  # Edit the command with gvim
  Start-Job -Name EditCMD -ScriptBlock { gvim "C:\Temp\ps_${Using:PID}.txt" }
  Wait-Job  -Name EditCMD

  # Get command back from file the temporary file and insert it into the command-line
  $NewInput  = (Get-Content -Path "C:\Temp\ps_${PID}.txt") -join "`n"
  [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::Insert($NewInput)
}
```

#### Questions

My current solution feels clunky and a somewhat fragile.
Are there other solutions?  Can the current solution be improved?

#### Environment

- OS Windows 10.0.19043.0
- Powershell version 5.1.19041.1320
- PSReadLine version 2.0.0

#### The solution I went with

Create a "baked" executable similar to what *mklement0* showed. I prefer `vim` for this instead of `gvim, as it runs directly in the console:

```
'@vim -f %*' > psvim.cmd
```

```
$env:EDITOR = "psvim"
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord "Alt+e" -Function ViEditVisually
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- PSReadLine *comes with the feature you're looking for*, namely the `ViEditVisually` function, and on Unix-like platforms it even has a default key binding.
- For the feature to work, you need to set `$env:VISUAL` or `$env:EDITOR` to the name / path of your editor executable.
- As of PSReadLine v2.1, if you also need to include *options* for your editor - such as `-f` for `gvim` - you need to create a *helper executable* that has the options "baked in".

  - Since creating a helper executable is cumbersome, a custom emulation of the feature, as you have attempted and as refined in [zett42's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42), may be the simpler solution for now. zett42's answer additionally links to a Gist that improves the original functionality by preserving cursor positions.
  - [GitHub issue #3214](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/3214) suggests adding support for recognizing executables *plus their options* in these environment variables.

**Details** below.

---

- The [PSReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/about/about_psreadline) module ***ships with* such a feature**, namely the **[`ViEditVisually`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/about/about_psreadline#vieditvisually) function**.
- Its **default key bindings**, if any, depend on PSReadLine's [*edit mode*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/about/about_psreadline), which you can set with `Set-PSReadLineOption -EditMode <mode>`:

  - `Windows` mode (default on Windows): *not bound*
  - `Emacs` mode (default on macOS and Linux): <kbd>Ctrl-x</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-e</kbd>
  - `Vi` mode: <kbd>v</kbd> in command mode (press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to enter it)
- Use [`Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlinekeyhandler) to establish a **custom key binding**, analogous to the approach in the question; e.g., to bind <kbd>Alt-e</kbd>:

  - `Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord Alt+e -Function ViEditVisually`
- For the function to work, **you must define the editor executable to use**, via either of the following environment variables, in order of precedence: **`$env:VISUAL` or `$env:EDITOR`**; if no (valid) editor is defined, a warning beep is emitted and no action is taken when the function is invoked.

  - E.g., to use the `nano` editor on macOS: `$env:VISUAL = 'nano'`
  - The **value must refer to an *executable file*** - either by full path or, more typically, by name only, in which case it must be located in a directory listed in `$env:PATH`

    - Note: `.ps1` scripts do *not* qualify as executable files, but *batch files* on Windows and shebang-line-based *shell scripts* on Unix-like platforms do.
  - **As of PSReadLine 2.1, including *options* for the executable - such as `--newindow --wait` for `code` (Visual Studio Code) is *not* supported**.

    - Therefore, **for now, if your editor of choice *requires options*, you need to create a *helper executable* that has these options "baked in"**; see examples below.
    - [GitHub issue #3214](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/3214) proposed adding support for allowing to specify the editor executable *plus options* as the environment-variable value, which is something that Git (which recognizes the same variables) already supports; for instance, you could then define:
      `$env:VISUAL = 'code --new-window --wait'`

---

**Example configuration with a helper executable** for `code` (Visual Studio Code):

- Create a helper executable in the user's home directory in this example:

  - On Windows:

    ```
    '@code --new-window --wait %*' > "$HOME\codewait.cmd"
    ```
  - On Unix-like platforms:

    ```
    "#!/bin/sh`ncode --new-window --wait `"$@`"" > "$HOME/codewait"; chmod a+x "$HOME/codewait"
    ```
- Add a definition of `$env:VISUAL` pointing to the helper executable to your `$PROFILE` file, along with defining a custom key binding, if desired:

```
$env:VISUAL = "$HOME/codewait"

# Custom key binding
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord Alt+e -Function ViEditVisually
```

Answer (score 4):

This code has some issues:

- Temp path is hardcoded, it should use `$env:temp` or better yet `[IO.Path]::GetTempPath()` (for cross-platform compatibility).
- After editing the line, it doesn't replace the whole line, only the text to the left of the cursor. As noted by [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0), we can simply [replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.psconsolereadline.replace) the existing buffer instead of erasing it, which fixes the problem.
- When using the right parameters for the editor, it is not required to create a job to wait for it. For VSCode this is [`--wait` (`-w`)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_core-cli-options) and for gvim this is [`--nofork` (`-f`)](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/vim1.html), which prevents these processes to detach from the console process so the PowerShell code waits until the user has closed the editor.
- The temporary file is not deleted after closing the editor.

Here is my attempt at fixing the code. I don't use `gvim`, so I tested it with VSCode `code.exe`. The code below contains a commented line for `gvim` too (confirmed working by the OP).

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord "Alt+e" -ScriptBlock {
    $CurrentInput = $null

    # Copy current console line
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::GetBufferState([ref] $CurrentInput, [ref] $null)

    # Save current console line to temp file
    $tempFilePath = Join-Path ([IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) "ps_$PID.ps1"
    Set-Content $tempFilePath -Value $CurrentInput -Encoding utf8

    # Edit the console line using VSCode
    code --new-window --wait $tempFilePath

    # Uncomment for using gvim editor instead
    # gvim -f $tempFilePath

    # The console doesn't like the CR character, so rejoin lines using LF only. 
    $editedInput = ((Get-Content -LiteralPath $tempFilePath) -join "`n").Trim()
    
    # Replace current console line with the content of the temp file
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::Replace(0, $currentInput.Length, $editedInput)

    Remove-Item $tempFilePath
}
```

**Update:**

This [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/zett42/6a602120c253a86e4eebe35fcd53752f) includes an updated version of the code. New features including saving/restoring the cursor position, passing the cursor position to VSCode and showing a message while the console is blocked.

**Notes:**

- A default installation of VSCode adds the directory of the VSCode binaries to `$env:PATH`, which enables us to write just `code` to launch the editor.
- While UTF-8 is the default encoding for cmdlets like `Set-Content` on [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), for *Windows PowerShell* the parameter `-Encoding utf8` is required to correctly save commands that contain Unicode characters. For `Get-Content` specifying the encoding isn't necessary, because Windows PowerShell adds a BOM which `Get-Content` detects and PowerShell Core defaults to UTF-8 again.
- To have <kbd>Alt+E</kbd> always available when you open a console, just add this code to your [`$profile` file](https://superuser.com/a/886960). Makes quick testing and editing of small code samples a breeze.
- VSCode settings - for most streamlined experience, enable "Auto Save: onWindowChange". Allows you to close the editor and save the file (update the console line) with a single press to <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd>.